# Django move database from one project to another without dataloss

Tags: python, django, sqlite

So I used to have my Django Project named "TestProject". Recently I started taking it more serious and renamed it to "ParadoxSite" (the name of the application).
Now I am wondering how I can transfer all data stored in `db.sqlite3` to this new project without dataloss. 
Maybe its possible to just run the migration flow, but I couldn't confirm this anywhere so didn't want to run the risk.

Comment: can't you just copy+paste `db.sqlite3`? if the only thing you've changed is projects name, and all models stay the same it may work

Comment: @oruchkin no as it will give an error "django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: ParadoxSite_profile"

Comment: Have you changed database name in `settings.py` ?

Comment: @antpngl92 I did not change it.

Comment: @kipteam you need to manually rename all tables in your db from `TestProject_TABLENAME` to `ParadoxSite_TABLENAME`, download sqlitedbrowser to better understanding what is inside of this db https://sqlitebrowser.org/ , you have about 10 default databases which you need to rename

Comment: The error says that there is no `Profile` model in your project. Make sure that there is one and migrations are made before feed the backup of your old DB.

Comment: @antpngl92 no, this error says that he is using database from `TestProject` in `ParadoxSite` project, and database by default hase a name of project before table name. There is nothing to do with migrations here

Comment: @oruchkin You are right, I haven't used SQLite for a while. You get `<project_name>/db.sqlite3` as a default DB name.